# How to concatenate 2 .csv files in 1 .csv file with multiple sheets using Batch commands

Tags: batch-file

There is a requirement in my project to automate some SQL queries and i did but after that one user came and ask that we do not want 2 separate .csv file we want 1 .csv file with multiple sheets

For eg. suppose there 2 .csv files "Text1.csv" and "Text2.csv" and we are sending this to users but they are coming back asking to do it like a "Text.csv" file with "sheet1" and "sheet2" sheets.

I have been using below

```
@echo off
cls
@echo *****************************Reports****************************
@echo.

sqlcmd -h-1 -S database -E -i "loc.sql" -o "loc2.csv"

sqlcmd -h-1 -S database -E -i "loc1.sql" -o "loc2.csv"

@echo Report is generated
@echo.
```

Note: I can not use any 3rd party tool like java or jscripts, neither i can use Visual studio for VBS, i have only option with batch cmd file

PS. if there is another kind of script that can write as a batch file without any need of 3rd party tool that will be great

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as the CSV format doesn't support multiple sheets (presuming that you are trying to view the file in excel).

The most you can do with a batch script is append one file onto another

```
copy File1+File2 NewFile
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @zhqiat.... but this way.. i can not resolve the query of user, we were sending excel(.xlsx) files before this and in that we were putting data manually in tabs. so now if i am automating they want the same and exact, the way it was

Comment: Or is there any way that i can create a excel file(.xls or .xlsx) through batch command?

Comment: a `csv` file is a textfile only. There are no tabs. If you want tabs, you can't use `csv` files. You have to use "real" Excel files `xls(x)`. But you can't process Excel files with batch, you have to use some other language (powershell might do the trick)

Comment: +1 to @Stephan XLSX files have to be created via a more high level language. You can try to use a batch script to call a vba script which creates your excel file.

Comment: Vbscript and Powershell can both modify excel files.

Comment: The sqlcmd can output as XML.  Excel can read the XML file just like it is an Excel file.  That is what we do here where I work but we use SAS to create the XML.  Not sure how you would create multiple sheets with your sqlcmd.

Comment: Thanks for that @stephan .... i think i will go with powershell.... just 1 ques in mind.... can we call powershell script through a batch file??